# RxJava BehaviorSubject subcribeoN

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

Below Code

why onnext called only once? When I remove subscribeOn it was called for every number.
when I subscribeOn io thread just once called (for 8658)

can someone explain it to me?

```
    val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
    subject.onNext(2121)
    subject.distinctUntilChanged().doOnNext {
        Log.d("AHMET VEFA SARUHAN", it.toString())
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(object : Observer<Int> {
        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {

        }

        override fun onNext(t: Int?) {

        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {

        }

        override fun onComplete() {

        }
    })
    subject.onNext(5436)
    subject.onNext(8658)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `subscribeOn`, the chain to observe the `BehaviorSubject` is established concurrently with the thread calling the `onNext`s. It takes time for a `subscribeOn` to take effect thus the main thread simply runs ahead and overwrites the subject's current value to the latest in the meantime.

There is no practical reason to use `subscribeOn` on a `Subject` in general.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your answer